Accessing the collections object and json data from a JavaScript file with Eleventy
I'm a very beginner in eleventy. And also in English!
I'm studying alone. I have a html page gallery.html with a dropdown menu. I have a javascript file that will add some html content dynamically depending on the item selected in the dropdown menu.
In the js file that is src/js I want to access to a collection object that I created in .eleventy.js named portraits. But i don't know how to to it.
In the js if I write collections.portraits, if I start, collections object is not known.
I also want to access from this js file to data in json files. these datas are in src/_data/photos.json. If I write photos.aKey in the js, if i start 11th server, photos is not defined.
How can i access to these datas from my js file ?
js calling json datas
if i start 11th server, and launch localhost, i have in the console :
photos is not defined. 
ReferenceError: photos is not defined

js using the collections object created in .eleventy.js
ReferenceError: collections is not defined


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Because 11ty is a static site generator you won't have access to the collections after the 11ty build has happened. You could, however, add all the code from the collection to your site and hide it by default. Your custom JS could toggle the desired block to visible on dropdown change.

thank you very much Makkusu. I understood now what to do.
